# Is it possible to handle up/down key in HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, html, events, autocomplete, key

I am building a autocomplete feature for input text field. Currently I could use mouse click to choose the selection, I'd like to add keyboard control to allow autocomplete control. I monitored the keycode in onkeyup event, it appears for up/down key, the key codes are both 0.

I am wondering whether there is any better way to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: May be you are getting zero because focus is on auto-complete list. Better have a look at jQuery's autocomplete plugin. It will give you idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keycodes 37 - 40 should do it for you. They map as 37=left, 38=up, 39=right, 40=down.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onkeydown.asp. It works for me in both FF3.5 and IE8.

Answer (score 1):

There's usually not a justifiable reason to re-invent the wheel.  That said, I would recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) with the [AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin.